# 'Add a Page' from a subsite creates the link at the root AND in /subsite/pages

Tags: sharepoint-online

Weird issue here. On some of my sites when I 'Add a Page' from the cog wheel, the location where the page is created displays incorrectly. See below:

Going to 'Add a Page' at this site (**xxxx.sharepoint.com/regions**) brings up the dialog box where I can name the page. The 'Find it at' text should display '**xxxx.sharepoint.com/regions/pages**', but instead it shows '**xxxx.sharepoint.com**'. The page then gets created at the correct location *and* a link is created at the root. This only occurs on some sites. This is causing the client headaches with the Managed Navigation!

I'm not really sure how to resolve this or where to look - I've checked the term store thoroughly. Any advice is appreciated!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. By having the tickbox "Create friendly URLs for new pages automatically" (in **Site Settings**>**Navigation**) selected the pages were being given friendly URLs for at the root of the Site.

Unticking this box removed the friendly URL and is now working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if on web settings (subsite settings > Navigation settings > Managed Navigation: Term Set) exists another term, different from the sitecollection and set this other one.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response. May you explain further? I don't fully understand and i cannot change the Managed Navigation.

Comment: Managed metadata is used to set friendly url navigation. Usually you could add as many term sets in root site collection navigation as you want but I advice you tu use a term set area for each web site in you site collection, an image example here > http://blog.navantis.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/IMAGE127.png  ; You can add it manually in central admin managed metadata service application or using powershell (you can find many script on the web).